# fibonacci sequence in c++

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I just start to learn programming and here is a problem about fibonacci sequence:

It is asked to make a function with parameter k(means k-order of fibonacci) and parameter n(means the n th member of sequence) and use that function to get the m th member of a k-order sequence.

```
f0 = 0, f1 =0, ....fk-2 =0, fk-1=1;
when n=k, k+1,...
fn= fn-1+fn-2+....+fn-k;     n=k,k+1,....
```

(letters and numbers on right-side of f are subscripts which mean the n th member, n-1 th member..)

following is my code:

```
int Fibonacci(int k, int n){
int result=0;
if (n==k-1) return 1;
if (n<k-1) return 0;
if (n>=k){
    for(int i=n-1; i>i-k-1;--i){
        result+=Fibonacci(k,i);
        cout<<result<<endl;
    }
return result;
}
```

}

---

new version

```
int result=0;
int Fibonacci(int k, int n){
if (n==k-1) return 1;
if (n<k-1) return 0;
if (n>=k){
    for(int i=n-1; i>n-k-1;--i){
        result+=Fibonacci(k,i);
        cout<<result<<endl;
    }
return result;
}
}
```

---

my question is why this code cannot come out correct answer? there should be some problems in the loop but I cannot find them. Will someone help me?

Comment: try initilizing result to 0

Comment: Actually I tried that but it still doesn't work. The result seems to be a very large negative number like -8499XXXX when I use the function Fibonacci(3,5) as an example....

Comment: If you tried it and still no work, then edit your code to include it.

Comment: use a debugger. test a simple case, e.g.: k=2.

Comment: can you tell us the input you tested it with? probably there might be an overflow...

Comment: Does it produce wrong answers or just not terminate?

Comment: After reading these comments above, I tried again by using Fibonacci(3,5) in VC 6.0, the result is -858993459 and this loop never end.

Comment: Nope, you did not try that. Your code does not initialize `result`. Do not expect us to reason about code other than what we see in the question. Why do you think it makes sense for you to not initialize `result`?

Comment: but seriously, if you fixed the non-initialize, you should edit the code so people aren't distracted....

Comment: well, when I initialize result =0 and this loop still cannot end. but this time the result is 1. it keeps inputting 1 in the screen .

Comment: i>i-k-1 ??
this should be i > n - k - 1, right?

Comment: yeah, loop condition is wrong, see answer below :)

Comment: No, **you** should fix the code. Please take more care.

Comment: well. thank you all. I have just fixed the code and added the new version above. Now it can end and input result correctly. I made two mistakes, I suppose. The first is the wrong condition in for-loop, as bgamlath and Richard said. The second is I should initialize "result=0" out of this function or it will be initialized each time when doing loop. Am I right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i=n-1; i>i-k-1;--i)
```

`i` will pretty much always be greater than `i-k-1`

Maybe you mean `for(int i=n-1; i>n-k-1;--i)`, but you should check.

Comment: What about underflow? :-P (Sorry for the nitpick. I actually know what you meant.)

Comment: @Eduardo ok, your one of those people who thinks `for(int i=0; i>=0; i++);` isnt an infinite loop. I appreciate that, and with modern processors you may even see such a loop end on a 32 bit system.